# How is @ used in MVC Razor and when is it required?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, hidden-field

I'm fairly new at MVC 3 but I came across a rather curious problem.
I'm using the Razor syntax, and according to VS, I don't need to prefix `@` to statements if they are immediately preceded with another `@` statement, or once inside the code, the prefix `@` is no longer required.

So here is my code in my View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("StudentSelect", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sSelect" }))  {

        Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedStudent);
        foreach (Classes.CStudent item in Model.Students)
        {
            <div class="studentSelect">
                <div class="studentname">@item.StudentName</div>
                <div>@item.Address</div>
            </div>   
        }
    }
```

Take not that the `Html.HiddenFor` and `foreach` lines do not have `@` prefix.
The generated HTML should produce a `<form>` followed by a `<input type="hidden">` field.
However, upon checking the HTML on the generated page, the hidden input field is missing.

```
<form action="/Home/StudentSelect" id="sSelect" method="post">                
   <div class="studentSelect">
        <div class="studentname">Name1</div>
        <div>AAA</div>
   </div>   
   <div class="studentSelect">
        <div class="studentname">Name2</div>
        <div>Address1</div>
   </div>   
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why isn't the hidden input not rendered?
Any clues would help. Thanks

By the way, this code compiles correct. However, if I prefix `@` in front of `Html.HiddenFor` my code does not compile and Visual Studio produces an error.

Comment: Can you provide the compile error? Views are typically not compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` serves two purposes. One to trigger "code mode" and one to shorthand `Response.Write`.

The instance of `@` preceding the `using` triggers "code mode". 
The instance of `@` preceding `item.Address` is equivalent to `Response.Write(item.Address);`.
You still require it for `Html.HiddenFor` as this returns an `MvcHtmlString` output that needs to be written to the response stream.

This line:

```
Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedStudent);
```

should be:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedStudent)
```

Notice the `;` is no longer required.

Comment: However, my code does not compile if I do put a `@` prefix. VS produces an error

Comment: Views are typically not compiled. Are you creating compiled views with a tool such as RazorGenerator?

Comment: No, I had VS to check the code upon compiling. I added the `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews` in the Project file

Comment: But this answers my question. Thanks! I can't accept it until later though

Comment: Raise the compile error as a new question and I'll take a look.

Comment: It's working now, I also had the `@for` before, but now I removed the prefix. The error VS was throwing was `Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@".`